# How to quantify the cable impedance for common mode voltages?

Tags: impedance, common-mode, coax

Since a coaxial cable is not twisted, in the case of a common-mode interference the positive and negative lines will pick up different voltages. This unbalanced impedance nature of the cable can be modeled as shown below(source output impedance is taken zero):

[image]

Imagine a 10m straight coaxial cable. Above Rc1 and Rc2 are the resistance of the inner and the outer cores. Lc1 and Cc1 represents the impedance of the inner core to a common mode interference. Similarly Rc2 and Lc2 represents the impedance of the outer core to a common mode interference.

But for a 10m coaxial cable how can I roughly estimate this Lc1, Lc2, Cc1 and Cc2 values? I want to model in SPICE simulation and see the affect of BNC coaxial cable's imbalance to the CMRR degradation.

Comment: The essence of **differential** signals is that they are treated **identically**. So if you want to transport a differential signal through a coax cable, the cable needs to have 2 signal conductors and a **grounded shield** around them. Or you would use **two** coax cables. Your setup seems to use the shield as one of the signal conductors, that defeats the whole purpose of using a coaxial cable as the shield should be grounded to prevent the inner conductor from picking up any signal.

Comment: The signal source is not differential. Im wondering the imbalance impedance of a 20m coaxial cable

Comment: Even if the wires are twisted, coupling to extermal interference WILL NOT BE Perfectly balanced.

Comment: https://www.ipen.br/biblioteca/cd/ieee/1999/Proceed/00535.pdf

Comment: Relevant on my website: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Articles/CableModel.html (first figure) 
 The transmission line model reduces at LF to an RLC model as above, but with Cc1 returned to Cc2 rather than GND. [Edited by a moderator.]

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a coaxial cable, you're not modeling the signal as differential.  The shield is assumed (on both sides) to be ground.  There's a lot of definitions of ground, but I'm using the most useful one...zero volts.

In reality, the lightspeed limit means there will be different potentials on the two ends of the coax, but on each side that potential is defined as zero volts.

The difference between a single ended connection and a differential connection is whether you compare your signal potential to a different nonzero potential, or to ground.  It just depends on which model works best for you.  You could, of course, use a coaxial cable to transfer a differential signal, but you'd lose the benefits of having a grounded shield (in this case "grounded" adds the additional implication of low impedance to circuit ground) and your only reward would be having to do a lot of additional math to work out the EMC implications.